# how can i find closest span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say i am having fallowing html structure-

```
<div data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Select One</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow">
        </span>
    </span>
    <select onchange="selectState(this,'ADDR_SHIP_STATE')" id="ADDR_SHIP_STATE" name="ADDR_SHIP_STATE"> 
        <option>Hi</option>
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>How</option>
        <option>are</option>
        <option>you</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

what i am trying to do is on change of select box, take the text of selected option and place it inside span(replace `select one` with this data) having class name `ui-btn-text`

below is the code which i ahve tried so for without any luck

```
function selectState(id,stateId){
var selectedState = $("#"+stateId+" option:selected").text();
$(id).closest("ui-btn-text").text(selectedState);
}
```

Please suggest me how can i do this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.closest()`[<sup>**ref**</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) will progress up the DOM but won't get down like `.parents()` does (btw, you didn't add the `.` (dot) for the class search but this is probably a typo)

Here is a try:

```
$(id).parent().find(".ui-btn-text").text(selectedState);
```

Comment: See this example: jsfiddle.net/8HfTa/5 (btw, ipr101 posted the same code...) - please also note I've corrected my code while creating the jsfiddle because your `ui-btn-text` was 2 level lower so I had to use `find` instead of `children` (the latter only travel a single level down)

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
function selectState(id, stateId) {
    var selectedState = $("#" + stateId + " option:selected").val();
    $(id).parents('div').find(".ui-btn-text").text(selectedState);
}
```

This will -

1. Find the parent 'div' of the 'select' element
2. Use `find` to get the `.ui-btn-text` element contained in the parent div

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/H2pea/1

Answer (score 1):

Using attributes like onchange is not really unobtrusive way if you use jQuery. This is better:

```
$('#ADDR_SHIP_STATE').change(function() {
    $(this).prev().find('.ui-btn-text').text($(this).val());
});
```